# encoding utf8 doesn't work sometimes php script integration

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

we have made an integration between an ERP (ms sql) and an e-commerce platform (php, mysql). This integration works without any problems for 1 year. Suddenly, last two weeks we are facing problem with php scripts of integration regarding encoding utf8 (language is Greek).Sometimes work fine and other times don't and print and write to database this for example

> ����������: S[Sneakers]; (���������� ���������) ������: S[�������� 2018-19]; (���������� ���������) Brand: E[REEBOK];

We have already done all the necessary actions, like:
We add on Apache char deault utf-8
We use with right way headers on scripts
We use mb_convert_encoding
We use meta charset="UTF-8"  on scripts

Does anyone have any other idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the DB connection set to the proper character set?

Comment: In addition to the above comment, are there any files introduced that would interact in any way?

Comment: @user3783243 Yes connection is set to the proper character set. Besides we haven't change anything last two weeks that happens this

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner what do you mean? can you be more specific?

Comment: Meaning; are there any files being sent by a service or client (uploaded) that would be beyond your control? Such as .csv or any other type of files that are sent to the server that would be set to a different character set. Plus, was there a server upgrade done? Sometimes, charset defaults get changed. The problem may also be coming from an external service, given if one is used. If files were saved by someone that were not of the right type and possibly saved as ANSI or UTF-8 with BOM (byte order mark) or without, then that too could cause this.

Comment: Why do you need the `mb_convert_encoding` if you support UTF8?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner ERP has web services. We have php scripts in order to connect to web services and get data from the ERP views. ERP server is a window server which had an update indeed. I don't know if i was helpful

Comment: @user3783243 just in case? Plus that is ERP provider guidline